# Android plugin conflict: Unable to convert classes into dex format

Tags: android, jar, libraries, android-library

I am trying to integrate Mobile Social Plugin into my Android game. I already have several other plugins including Admob Ads and Google Play Games services and Unity IAP.

I did have some problems getting it to work and the support team helped me in this thread: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-mobile-social-plugin.229961/page-7#post-2601452

They emailed me a google-play-services.jar file to put in my project, which I did.

Now when I try to build I get this error:

> **Build failure**
>
> Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.

The console spits out this:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Android SDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity 5\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -
stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoJellyBeanMr2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBeanMr2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorListenerCompat;
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Unity Projects\SwitchShoot\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\AmazonAppStore\bin\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/unity/
ignored resource com/unity/purchasing/
ignored resource com/unity/purchasing/amazon/
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/AmazonPurchasing.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/AmazonPurchasing$1.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/AmazonPurchasing$2.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/AmazonPurchasing$3.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/AmazonPurchasing$4.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/AmazonPurchasing$LocaleNotFoundException.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/AmazonPurchasingService.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/CurrencyMapper.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/amazon/IPurchasingService.class...
processing archive C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Unity Projects\SwitchShoot\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\AmazonAppStore\libs\.\in-app-purchasing-1.0.3.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
processing com/amazon/device/iap/package-info.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/PurchasingListener.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/PurchasingService.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/ResponseReceiver.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/a/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/a/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/a/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/a/c$1.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/a/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/a/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/a/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/a/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/a/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/b/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/b/a$1.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/b/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/b/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/b/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/c/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/c/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/c/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/c/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/d/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/d/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/d/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/d/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/e.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/e/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/e/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/e/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/e/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/e$1.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/f.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/f/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/f/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/f/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/g.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/g/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/g/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/h.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/h/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/b/i.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/c/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/c/a$1.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/c/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/c/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/c/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/c/e.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/e.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/model/ProductBuilder.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/model/ProductDataResponseBuilder.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/model/PurchaseResponseBuilder.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/model/PurchaseUpdatesResponseBuilder.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/model/ReceiptBuilder.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/model/UserDataBuilder.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/model/UserDataResponseBuilder.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/model/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/util/MetricsHelper.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/util/a.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/util/a$1.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/util/b.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/util/c.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/util/d.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/internal/util/e.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/package-info.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/FulfillmentResult.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/Product.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/Product$1.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/ProductDataResponse.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/ProductDataResponse$RequestStatus.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/ProductType.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/PurchaseResponse.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/PurchaseResponse$RequestStatus.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/PurchaseUpdatesResponse.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/PurchaseUpdatesResponse$RequestStatus.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/Receipt.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/RequestId.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/RequestId$1.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/UserData.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/UserData$1.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/UserDataResponse.class...
processing com/amazon/device/iap/model/UserDataResponse$RequestStatus.class...
processing archive C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Unity Projects\SwitchShoot\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleAIDL\bin\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/android/
ignored resource com/android/vending/
ignored resource com/android/vending/billing/
processing com/android/vending/billing/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class...
ignored resource C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Unity Projects\SwitchShoot\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs\.\PLUGIN_JAR_GOES_HERE
processing archive C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Unity Projects\SwitchShoot\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin\libs\.\unity-plugin-library.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/unity/
processing com/google/unity/BuildConfig.class...
ignored resource com/google/unity/ads/
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Banner$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$4.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/Interstitial$5.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/PluginUtils.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$1$1.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$2.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/RewardBasedVideo$3.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityBannerAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityInterstitialAdListener.class...
processing com/google/unity/ads/UnityRewardBasedVideoAdListener.class...
processing archive C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Unity Projects\SwitchShoot\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlay\bin\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/unity/
ignored resource com/unity/purchasing/
ignored resource com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/ActivityLauncher.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1$1.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1$2.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$2.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceProcessor.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts$PurchaseState.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts$ResponseCode.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayBillingUnAvailableException.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$1.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$2.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$3.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$4.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IActivityLauncher.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IBillingServiceManager.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabException.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$1.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$2.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$3.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$4.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$OnConsumeFinishedListener.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$OnConsumeMultiFinishedListener.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$OnIabSetupFinishedListener.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$QueryInventoryFinishedListener.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabResult.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Inventory.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Purchase.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/PurchaseActivity.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/PurchaseFailedEvent.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/SkuDetails.class...
processing archive C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Unity Projects\SwitchShoot\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\MainLibProj\libs\.\play-games-plugin-support.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/games/
ignored resource com/google/games/bridge/
processing com/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/NativeBridgeActivity.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$1.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$2.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$3.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$TokenRequest.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenPendingResult.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenResult.class...
processing archive C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Unity Projects\SwitchShoot\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\bin\classes.jar...
ignored resource .readme
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource android/
ignored resource android/support/
ignored resource android/support/v7/
ignored resource android/support/v7/app/
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$LayoutParams.class...
processing android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$NavigationMode.class...
processi<message truncated>
```

I've emailed the support team again but just wanted to open this up to you kind folks to see if I can speed this up. I'm tantalisingly close to hitting beta just as soon as I can get this working!

I've done some digging around and from what I can see this is caused by conflicts with some JAR files in my project. Some people have said they delete a support jar and it works, while others are deleting duplicate classes within the jar.

This is the full list of all .jar files in my entire project:

[JARS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szaY9.png)

How can I find out where the problem lies and what steps to take to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all duplicate .jar files of your project.